# looping the key/value pairs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I'm trying to loop the key/value pairs I receive below in my query and console out the email address. What I'm I doing wrong?

JSON I receive...

```
{"ERRORS":[],"DATA":[{"INCENTIVEID":"1","CREATED":"","EMAIL":"email","RECIPIENTID":"1","NAME":"glyn","ACTIVE":0,"MODIFIED":"","MOBILE":"11111111111"},{"INCENTIVEID":"1","CREATED":"","EMAIL":"eee","RECIPIENTID":"2","NAME":"edem","ACTIVE":0,"MODIFIED":"","MOBILE":"11111111111"}],"MESSAGES":[]}
```

Current Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var digits = /^\d{11}$/;
        $("#mobile").on("keyup keypress", function(){

            if (digits.test(this.value)) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://api.domain.com/recipients/lookup",
                    data: {
                        mobile: this.value,
                        incentiveID:  $("#incentiveID").val()
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $.each(data.DATA, function(index, value) {
                          console.log(value.EMAIL);
                        });
                         console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: this part " console.log(value.EMAIL);" give me undefined. How do I get all the email addresses returned from the Json call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The e-mails are within the `DATA` array; you should use `data.DATA` instead of just `data`, which refers to the entire JSON object:

```
$.each(data.DATA, function(index, value) {
  console.log(value.EMAIL);
});
```

Comment: I tried that but with the above code this gave me an error: TypeError: a is undefined

Comment: @Spike: You sure you don't have a typo? I don't reference any variable called `a` in the above code. Can you paste your new code?

Comment: edit code above. error is TypeError: a is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

...=[]),o&&(e=" "+e);while(e){k=!1;if(j=B.exec(e))e=e.slice(j[0].length),k=d.push({...

Comment: That's a jQuery error. Can you paste me the exact content of `data`? Is it a string or a JSON object?

Comment: That is because there is a null value provided to the $.each function. It is a jquery error, it more than likely comes from your JSON output than the jquery loop.

Comment: the JSON I receive is at the top of my question. this is what I get back.

Comment: @Spike: Something's not right. If you try the above code with the JSON object that you mentioned, it works flawlessly as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/yA5MU/. Can you do `console.log(data)` and show me the result within the success handler?

Comment: strange, I cannot workout whats going on here. To me this should work and the example João gave looks right yes the code I am running is the same as above no different at all. the json data is the same too. using jquery-1.8.0.min.js

Comment: I have seemed to reslove the issue by added type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",

Answer (score 0):

Added below and issue was resolved. anyone know why?

type: "GET",
dataType: "json",